# Robot Orientation Planning

Tags: matlab, path, robotics

I am solving motion planning problem for a robot, and I am a kind of confuse about the planning for the robot orientation along the path generated. Let's assume a path planner has been utilized to search for a path from start-configuration to a goal-configuration assuming the robot is a mass point in the space, resulted in cartesian path (X_i,Y_i). For the robot the orientation need to be planned as well so that robot location should be in the form (X_i,Y_i,theta_i), however, I do not have the concepts of how to go from having a path in the form (X_i,Y_i) and plan the robot's orientation along the waypoints?

Comment: the orientation, aka attitude, of this point robot can be simplified to an angle, for each point along the path. If you define attitude 0 when robot facing east, or right hand side, then you define attitude rotation for instance clockwise positive attitude angles, then you can tell where is the robot looking at on each point of the path.

Comment: in a 3D scenario you'd need 2 angles.

Comment: I cannot understand your point...in case I do have path planner that only output path as a sequence of xy-points, how can I modify it so that I can integrate as well the orientation of the robot (theta)?